# Call function once and detatch itself

Tags: javascript

I want to implement in pure Javascript the following

A button, when clicked, calls a function

```
<button id= "myButton", onclick="onlyOnce()">Hit me</button>
```

`onlyOnce` sets some vars and calls another function. Then `onlyOnce` detaches itself from the button and the other function adds it self on the button, so now its called with every click

I cannot make it work

Here is the code

```
<button id= "myButton", onclick="onlyOnce()">Hit me</button>

function onlyOnce() {
    console.log("onlyOnce called!");
    //do some code...
    otherFunction();
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", otherFunction, false);    
    document.getElementById("myButton").removeEventListener("click", onlyOnce, false);  
}

function otherFunction() {
    console.log("otherFunction called!");
}
```

When I hit the button the first time, I see `onlyOnce called!` and `otherFunction called!`, so this is correct.

When I continue to hit the button I still see `onlyOnce called!` and `otherFunction called!`, so this is wrong because `onlyOnce` did not detached itself. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In this instance it'd be simpler to use a boolean (eg. `firstCall`) and set it to false as the last thing when it's called the first time. Then you can simply use `if (firstCall) { } else { }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it is like this:

```
function onlyOnce() {

    console.log("onlyOnce called!");

   //do some code...
   otherFunction();

   document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = otherFunction; // assign the other function to the onclick property of the element.
}
```

Comment: Cleaner answer so far, with less amount of editing. Practically I see that it works. Theoretically I dont get why. Has the same logic as mine, only `.onclick` can overwright `add/removeEventListener`? Please explain the logic behind it. Thanks

Comment: It replaces the old function that you set as the onclick function when you created the button(  <button id= "myButton", onclick="onlyOnce()" ) and reassigns the other function to the onclick property of the button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is better solution (without overwriting reference to other function):

```
function onlyOnce() {
    console.log("onlyOnce called!");
    //do some code...
    otherFunction();
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", otherFunction, false);    
    document.getElementById("myButton").removeEventListener("click", onlyOnce, false);  
}

function otherFunction() {
    console.log("otherFunction called!");
}

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', onlyOnce);
```

And HTML:

```
<button id= "myButton">Hit me</button>
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7pa9uLyu/1/)

Comment: Aha, so the only difference is that you dont predefine the `onClick` in the HTML part. Right?

Comment: Also adding event listener programatically in javascript instead of declarative syntax in HTML.

Comment: No problem. Would appreciate if you could mark your question as solved by accepting answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a function which delegates all calls to other functions, configured when you create the event handler

```
function once(first,others){
  var isFirstTime = true;
  return function(e){
        if(isFirstTime){
            first(e);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        else{
            others(e)  
        }
  }
}
```

An example is below

```js
function once(first,others){
  var isFirstTime = true;
  return function(e){
        if(isFirstTime){
            first(e);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        else{
            others(e)  
        }
  }
}

function onceOnly(){
    console.log("once only");  
}

function everyOtherTime(){
    console.log("other times");  
}

document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click",once(onceOnly,everyOtherTime))
```

```html
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button id= "myButton", onclick="onlyOnce()">Hit me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var onlyOnce = function() {
            onlyOnce = function(){}; //As soon as it runs, it will be set to an empty object and will not run again
            console.log("onlyOnce called!");

            //do some code...
            otherFunction();
            document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", otherFunction, false);    
            document.getElementById("myButton").removeEventListener("click", onlyOnce, false);  
        }

        function otherFunction() {
            console.log("otherFunction called!");
        }
    </script>
    /* alternative
    var onlyOnce = function() { 
     console.log("onlyOnce called!"); 
     onlyOnce = otherFunction; 
     //do some code... 
     otherFunction(); 
   } 
  */
</body>
```

Best wishes!

Comment: OK, it will not run again. But does it actually gets detatched?

Comment: I dont think it get detached because when I imlement your solution and do `getEventListeners(myButton)` on my console, I get `Object {click: Array[2]}` and when I implement other solutions I get `Object {click: Array[1]}`

Comment: var onlyOnce = function() {
    console.log("onlyOnce called!");
    onlyOnce = otherFunction;
    //do some code...
    otherFunction();
} It does not detach but it's a trick for it not to run again, above is another, setting  onlyOnce to otherFunction after the initial run.

Comment: Setting onlyOnce = otherFunction will remove the initial funtionalities of onlyOnce and give it otherFunction. I hope this helps!